# GWT Java - Image handling - displaying a new image to replace an existing using IUploader

Tags: java, gwt

I am obtaining a list of badges from the database, displaying the pictures of the badges with a description and allowing the user to change the picture. When the user selects a new picture it is not being displayed and I can not work out why (there are no error messages in the log). The IUploader is being triggered followed by the OnLoadPreloadedImageHandler.

Any assistance wold be greatly appreciated.

The relevant code is:

```
for (final Six sixDescription : sixList) {

            //Determine whether or not to display archived Six
            if ((showArchived.equals("Yes")) ||
                    ((showArchived.equals("No")) && (sixDescription.getSixArchived() == null))) {

                //Store the Six Primary Key.
                final String storeSixID = sixDescription.getSixId();

                // A panel where the thumbnails of upload images will be shown
                final HorizontalPanel existingPanelImages = new HorizontalPanel();

                //Increment the row index.
                row++;row++;

                //Allow update of a Six badge

                //Six replacement Picture Handler
                // Load the image in the document and in the case of success attach it to the viewer
                // Attach a replacement image to the pictures viewer
                final OnLoadPreloadedImageHandler showNewImage = new OnLoadPreloadedImageHandler() {
                    public void onLoad(PreloadedImage image) {
                        image.setWidth("75px");
                        existingPanelImages.clear();
                        existingPanelImages.add(image);
                        Window.alert("OnLoadPreloadedImageHandler");
                    }
                };

                final IUploader.OnFinishUploaderHandler onReplaceFinishUploaderHandler = new IUploader.OnFinishUploaderHandler() {
                    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                    public void onFinish(IUploader uploader) {
                        if (uploader.getStatus() == Status.SUCCESS) {
                            new PreloadedImage(uploader.fileUrl(), showNewImage);

                            //The server sends useful information to the client by default
                            UploadedInfo info = uploader.getServerInfo();
                                            System.out.println("File name " + info.name);
                                            System.out.println("File content-type " + info.ctype);
                                            System.out.println("File size " + info.size);               

                            // You can send any customised message and parse it
                                            System.out.println("Server message " + info.message);
                            //Store path to image;
                            imagePath = info.message;

                            if (info.name != null) {
                                fileName.setText(info.name);
                            }
                            Window.alert("IUploader");
                        }
                    }
                };

                // Attach the image viewer to the document so we can get the Award image.
                //TODO Delete temporary image when finished.
                Window.alert("Existing");
                flexTable_Existing.setWidget(row, 0, existingPanelImages);
                existingPanelImages.setSize("75", "75");
                existingPanelImages.setBorderWidth(1);
                existingPanelImages.clear();
                existingPanelImages.setStyleName("gwt-TextBox");
                flexTable_Existing.getCellFormatter().setVerticalAlignment(row, 0, HasVerticalAlignment.ALIGN_TOP);
                flexTable_Existing.getCellFormatter().setHorizontalAlignment(row, 0, HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_CENTER);

                //Display the current image.
                String imageDataString = sixDescription.getSixPicture();
                Image existingImage = new Image(imageDataString);
                existingImage.setWidth("75px");
                existingImage.setHeight("75px");
                existingImage.setStyleName("gwt-TextBox");
                flexTable_Existing.setWidget(row, 0, existingImage);


                // Create a new uploader panel and attach it to a document
                SingleUploader defaultUploader = new SingleUploader();
                defaultUploader.setAutoSubmit(true);
                defaultUploader.setValidExtensions("gif");
                defaultUploader.setEnabled(true);
                defaultUploader.avoidRepeatFiles(false);
                defaultUploader.setStyleName("gwt-TextBox");

                // Add a finish handler which will load the image once the upload finishes
                defaultUploader.addOnFinishUploadHandler(onReplaceFinishUploaderHandler);
                defaultUploader.getFileInput().getWidget().setStyleName("customButton");
                defaultUploader.getFileInput().getWidget().setSize("180px", "20px");

                row++;
                flexTable_Existing.setWidget(row, 0, defaultUploader);
                flexTable_Existing.getCellFormatter().setVerticalAlignment(row, 0, HasVerticalAlignment.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
                flexTable_Existing.getCellFormatter().setHorizontalAlignment(row, 0, HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_LEFT);

                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


                row--;
                //Allow update of a Six Name
                final TextBox textBoxExistingSixName = new TextBox();
                textBoxExistingSixName.setStyleName("gwt-TextBox");
                textBoxExistingSixName.setText(sixDescription.getSixName());
                textBoxExistingSixName.setWidth("100px");
                flexTable_Existing.setWidget(row, 1, textBoxExistingSixName);
                flexTable_Existing.getCellFormatter().setVerticalAlignment(row, 1, HasVerticalAlignment.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
                flexTable_Existing.getCellFormatter().setHorizontalAlignment(row, 1, HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_LEFT);

                //Allow update of an archive date for the Six
                final DateBox dateBoxExistingArchived = new DateBox();
                dateBoxExistingArchived.setFormat(new DefaultFormat(DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")));
                dateBoxExistingArchived.setStyleName("gwt-TextBox");
                dateBoxExistingArchived.setValue(sixDescription.getSixArchived());
                dateBoxExistingArchived.setWidth("100px");
                flexTable_Existing.setWidget(row, 2, dateBoxExistingArchived);
                flexTable_Existing.getCellFormatter().setVerticalAlignment(row, 2, HasVerticalAlignment.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
                flexTable_Existing.getCellFormatter().setHorizontalAlignment(row, 2, HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_LEFT);
            }   
        }
    }
```

Comment: i think its because of HorzontalPanel is not redrawing..

Comment: Hi Mohammed, How do I get it to redraw please. I received an email notification that contained "call this after uploading new image.... existingPanelImages.layout(); ". However, that comment seems to have been deleted. I tried placing "existingPanelImages.layout();" after "existingPanelImages.add(existingImage);" however, I get an error message and I can not find the correct syntax -- Multiple markers at this line
 - The method layout() is undefined for the type 
  HorizontalPanel
 - Line breakpoint:SixView [line: 594] - 
  onLoad(PreloadedImage)    Regards, Glyn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my issue by making the following code change:

```
//Six replacement Picture Handler
// Load the image in the document and in the case of success attach it to the viewer
// Attach a replacement image to the pictures viewer
final int currentRow = row+2;
final OnLoadPreloadedImageHandler showNewImage = new OnLoadPreloadedImageHandler() {
    public void onLoad(PreloadedImage existingImage) {
        image.setWidth("75px");
        existingPanelImages.clear();
        existingPanelImages.add(existingImage);
        flexTable_Existing.setWidget(currentRow, 0, existingPanelImages);
        existingPanelImages.setSize("75px", "75px");
        existingPanelImages.setBorderWidth(1);
        existingPanelImages.setStyleName("gwt-TextBox");
        flexTable_Existing.getCellFormatter().setVerticalAlignment(currentRow, 0, HasVerticalAlignment.ALIGN_TOP);
        flexTable_Existing.getCellFormatter().setHorizontalAlignment(currentRow, 0, HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_CENTER);
    }
};
```

The issue I have now is that the image is being displayed full size instead of 75px by 75px.

I hope this is of some use to others.

Regards,

Glyn